# Parallelize Functions in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a function `ComparePatchMany` written in numpy, which does some basic matrix functions (dot product, diagonal, etc), and due to the size of matrices I'm using, is too slow. In order to achieve some speedup, I want to run calls to this function in parallel. Because of memory issues, I can't seem to call this on any more than 100 stacked matrices at a time. So simply running ComparePatchMany on a giant matrix is out (though it works in MatLab).

What I have right now is:

```
def comparePatchManyRunner(tex_flat,imMask_flat,s_tex,metrics,i):
    metrics[i] = ComparePatchMany.main(tex_flat[imMask_flat==1,:],np.reshape(s_tex[:,i],(-1,1)))

# N = 100
def main(TexLib,tex,OperationMask,N,gpu=0):

    if gpu:
        print 'ERROR: GPU Capability not set'
    else:
        tex_flat = np.array([tex.flatten('F')]).T

    CreateGrid = np.ones((TexLib.Gr.l_y.shape[1],TexLib.Gr.l_x.shape[1]))
    PatchMap = np.nan*CreateGrid
    MetricMap = np.nan*CreateGrid
    list_of_patches = np.argwhere(CreateGrid>0)

    for i in range(list_of_patches.shape[0]):
        y,x = list_of_patches[i]
        imMask = TexLib.obtainMask(y,x)
        Box = [TexLib.Gr.l_x[0,x],TexLib.Gr.l_x[-1,x],TexLib.Gr.l_y[0,y],TexLib.Gr.l_y[-1,y]]

        imMaskO = imMask
        imMask = imMask & OperationMask

        imMask_flat = np.dstack((imMask,imMask,imMask))

        if gpu:
            print 'ERROR! GPU Capability not yet implemented'
            # TODO
        else:
            imMask_flat = imMask_flat.flatten('F')

        if np.sum(imMask)<8:
            continue

        indd_s = np.random.randint(TexLib.NumTexs,size=(1,N*5))

        s_tex = TexLib.ImW[imMask_flat==1][:,np.squeeze(indd_s)]
        s_tex = s_tex.astype('float32')

        if gpu:
            print 'ERROR! GPU Capability not yet implemented'
            # TODO
        else:
            metrics = np.zeros((N*5,1))
            shared_arr = multiprocessing.Array('d',metrics)

            processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=comparePatchManyRunner, args=(tex_flat,imMask_flat,s_tex,shared_arr,i)) for i in xrange(N*5)]
            for p in processes:
                p.start()
            for p in processes:
                p.join()
            metrics = shared_arr
            print metrics
```

I think this may be creating 500 processes, which could be an issue. One problem I keep running into with this and previous versions is `IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`, which originates from `p.start()`.

I'm working on Windows with Python 2.7, NumPy 1.8, and SciPy 0.13.2.

EDIT:

Comments suggested I use pools. So I'm trying this:

```
metrics = np.zeros((N*5,1))
shared_arr = multiprocessing.Array('d',metrics,lock=False)
po = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
po.map_async(comparePatchManyRunner,((tex_flat,imMask_flat,s_tex,shared_arr,idex) for idex in xrange(N*5)))
```

But it doesn't seem to be writing anything to shared_arr, and I keep getting a PicklingError:

```
Exception in thread Thread-29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_500'>: attribute lookup multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_500 failed
```

Comment: Having 500 processes is *useless*. You should take a look at [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) which will spawn some worker processes and handle them for you.

Comment: I'm trying to get `multiprocessing.Pool` working, but it's still giving me some trouble, I've added new edits above.

Comment: Or try [`joblib`](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/). But I'd recommend profiling first to find the hotspots. You might just need a better BLAS library.

Comment: @larsmans Profiling is how I know that the hotspot is this function that contains numpy.dot. The matrices are large, and I make so many calls to numpy.dot that it all just adds up. More than 60% of my time is spent there.

Comment: Have you got NumPy >=1.7.1? What does the function look like?

Comment: @larsmans Yeah, NP 1.8. The function (`ComparePatchMany`), finds the diagonal of the dot product of the difference between two matrices (`np.dot(p_diff.T,p_diff)`). The original MatLab version of the function handled matrices of size 8265x500 (the vectorized code was very fast), but Numpy wasn't able to handle matrices of that size. So what I'm trying to do instead is to run the function 500 times for matrices of size 8265x1.

Comment: Even the old NumPy 1.6.1 that I have here can do such a multiplication in a fraction of a second. Sounds like a configuration problem, and even if your matrices were really large, reducing to a loop over vectors is not a good idea (a loop over smaller matrices is always better).

Comment: @larsmans Multiplication is fast, about 0.002 s for each call. I just have to do it 368,025 times. I want to avoid reducing that number if at all possible, so my only other option is to run multiple instances of the function at the same time.

Comment: What I'm saying is that multiplying a 500×8265 with its transpose should be no problem either.

Comment: @larsmans Huh, there must have been something wrong with my original code. I was getting memory errors when I ran matrices of that size. I wrote it all again and it seems to be working now.